# Escape "[]" characters in a semicolon-separated list in CMake

Tags: cmake

I found "[" and "]" might have special meanings in a semicolon-separated list in `CMake`. When I try this code in `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
set(XX "a" "b" "[" "]")
message("${XX}")

foreach(x ${XX})
        message("--> ${x}")
endforeach()
```

I expect the result:

```
a;b;[;]
--> a
--> b
--> [
--> ]
```

However I got this:

```
a;b;[;]
--> a
--> b
--> [;]
```

I didn't find any documentation for the usage of "[" and "]". Is it possible to escape these characters so that I can get the expected result? I am using `CMake 2.8.12.2`. Thanks for any  help :)

Comment: I've found this [bug](http://public.kitware.com/Bug/view.php?id=9317).

Comment: Thank you :)  Maybe I need to replace brackets with other strings and then replace them back to workaround this bug.

Comment: I need to extract strings from some config files from 3rd-party libraries and then generate an xml file for my android project. unfortunately the config files contain brackets and make CMake confused.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-language.7.html#bracket-argument) opening square bracket definitely has a special meaning:

> **Note:** CMake versions prior to 3.0 do not support bracket arguments. They interpret the opening bracket as the start of an Unquoted Argument.

So the problem is mixing Quoted and Unquoted arguments. Possible workaround in your case is to replace opening square bracket to something else in initialization and later replace it back, like this:

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED (VERSION 2.8.11)
PROJECT (HELLO NONE)

SET(XX a b BRACKET ])

MESSAGE("${XX}")

FOREACH(x ${XX})
    STRING(REGEX REPLACE "BRACKET" "[" x ${x})
    MESSAGE("--> ${x}")
ENDFOREACH()
```

Comment: The handling of closing bracket is also weird. For example, if you try `set(XX "a" "b" "]" "c" "d")`, you will get `--> ];c;d` instead of 3 separated items. I end up with the workround by replacing all brackets with something else and then replace them back. It is dirty but works for me. :)

Comment: Bracketed arguments require double brackets, `[[...]]`, or with a matching sequence of `=` between them; `[===[...]===]`.  Single brackets shouldn't be interpreted as a bracketed argument (or bracketed comment).

Answer (score 1):

As noted in another answer, the square brackets are now used to delimit ["long form" arguments](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/manual/cmake-language.7.html#bracket-argument) or [long form comments](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/manual/cmake-language.7.html#bracket-comment), as well documented in CMake 3.0 and later.

A single pair of square brackets with ; inside have also long been used to designate registry [key;value] pairs on Windows. An example of this behavior is shown in the CMake file [InstallRequiredSystemLibraries.cmake](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/90825908/Modules/InstallRequiredSystemLibraries.cmake#L93-L94) :

```
get_filename_component(msvc_install_dir
  "[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\VisualStudio\\8.0;InstallDir]" ABSOLUTE)
```

The way it's implemented has the unfortunate side effect of causing confusion when somebody wants to have list values containing square brackets, hence this question on SO.

Comment: Unfortunately escaping square brackets does not work.  `Invalid escape sequence \[`

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'll edit my answer to remove the suggestion of trying the \\[ escape.