# SFML library-NOTFOUND error during MinGW build

Tags: c++, cmake, mingw, sfml

I'm trying to build a test SFML program the following way:

Windows 10, CLion, MinGW64, CMake, SFML-2.5.1

**CmakeList.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(Test_sfml_cmake_)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

set(SFML_DIR "SFML-2.5.1/lib/cmake/SFML")

find_package(SFML 2.5 COMPONENTS graphics audio REQUIRED)
add_executable(SFMLTest main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(SFMLTest sfml-graphics sfml-audio)
```

The MinGW build fails with an error (full output):

```
-- Found SFML 2.5.1 in D:/_Documents/Cpp Projects/Test_sfml[cmake]/SFML-2.5.1/lib/cmake/SFML
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: D:/_Documents/Cpp Projects/Test_sfml[cmake]/cmake-build-debug
Scanning dependencies of target SFMLTest
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** No rule to make target 'sfml-audio-NOTFOUND', needed by 'SFMLTest.exe'.  Stop.
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/SFMLTest.dir/main.cpp.obj
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:72: CMakeFiles/SFMLTest.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:83: all] Error 2
```

Anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: Did you try using the `SFML_*` variables provided by the `find_package(SFML ...)` call, as seen in the response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45671299/linking-sfml-with-cmake-windows-mingw)?

Comment: The older version of SFML is used there, so not working for this case

Comment: Ok, you are correct; the `sfml-graphics` syntax should work for the latest SFML. Can you please provide your **full** CMake output? The fact that the `sfml-*` targets were set to `-NOTFOUND` makes me think something may have gone wrong earlier in the process. Your CMake output may show this.

Comment: Updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your full path to the SFML library contains brackets `[ ]`:

```
"D:/_Documents/Cpp Projects/Test_sfml[cmake]/SFML-2.5.1"
```

This is a problem for CMake (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26057678/3987854)), as square brackets are special characters used to denote [bracket arguments](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-language.7.html#bracket-argument) and quotes.

Using square brackets in the path causes weird behavior in this case, because the `find_package` call appears to succeed, but your `sfml-*` targets are not created properly (e.g. `sfml-audio-NOTFOUND`).

So, just change the directory name of your project to *remove* the square brackets, re-run CMake, then re-build.